# MySQL query selecting all closed records per team per yearly quarter

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to create a query that will pull all current records with a 'CLOSED' status, group said records by TEAM, and then display the counts of the records per quarter. My query thus far is -

```
SELECT teamNumber, YEAR(Closed) AS year, QUARTER(Closed) AS quarter, COUNT(caseID) AS Records
  FROM Records
 WHERE Status = 'CLOSED'
 GROUP BY teamNumber, QUARTER(Closed)
 ORDER BY QUARTER(Closed)
```

This gets me almost there. It's counting the records by team and breaking it out by quarter.

| team | year | quarter | Records |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| team1 | 2023 | 1 | 4 |
| team2 | 2023 | 1 | 7 |
| team1 | 2023 | 2 | 1 |
| team2 | 2023 | 2 | 3 |

However, I need the result to look like this -

| team | year | q1 | q2 | q3 | q4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| team1 | 2023 | 4 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| team2 | 2023 | 7 | 3 | 0 | 0 |

Is this possible with just a MySQL query?

My goal is to display the end result via PHP. Should I be looking at running the query and then manipulating the data within PHP, or let the query manipulate the data and then just worry about displaying within PHP?

Comment: you could investigate doing this with a PIVOT query I think. Or yes, it would be achievable in PHP with a bit of consideration and effort.

Comment: I've never tried a PIVOT query in MySQL but I gave it a go. If the COUNT(caseID) was just caseID, i think it would work. But I keep getting an error 1111: Invalid use of group function.  <br/>SELECT teamNumber, YEAR(Closed) AS year, SUM(CASE
  WHEN QUARTER(Closed) = 1 THEN COUNT(caseID) ELSE 0 END
) AS q1
  FROM Records
 WHERE Status = 'CLOSED'
 GROUP BY teamNumber;

Comment: I meant to say the query works if the COUNT wasn't there. The COUNT appears to be causing the error 1111.

Comment: Don't forget to include `YEAR(Closed)` in the `GROUP BY`.

Comment: got it figured out. `SELECT teamNumber, YEAR(Closed) AS year, 
SUM(CASE WHEN QUARTER(Closed) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS q1,
SUM(CASE WHEN QUARTER(Closed) = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS q2,
SUM(CASE WHEN QUARTER(Closed) = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS q3,
SUM(CASE WHEN QUARTER(Closed) = 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS q4
 FROM Records
 WHERE Status = 'CLOSED'
 GROUP BY teamNumber, YEAR(Closed);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can import your query in to a customized array and use it to show the table as you want. Something like this:

```
<?php

$result = array();

while($list = fetch($query)) {
    $result[$list['teamNumber']]['year'] = $list['year'];
    $result[$list['teamNumber']]['quarter'.$list['quarter']] = $list['Records'];
}

?>

<table>
<tr>
<td>team</td>
<td>year</td>
<td>q1</td>
<td>q2</td>
<td>q3</td>
<td>q4</td>
</tr>

<?php foreach($result as $team => $data) { ?>

<tr>
<td><?= $team; ?></td>
<td><?= $data['year']; ?></td>
<td><?= intval($data['quarter1']); ?></td>
<td><?= intval($data['quarter2']); ?></td>
<td><?= intval($data['quarter3']); ?></td>
<td><?= intval($data['quarter4']); ?></td>
</tr>

<?php } ?>
</table>
```

not need to say that blow line is just an example for your fetch function:

```
$list = fetch($query)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I initially received an undefined function fetch() error. I think I might need to use DBO. I'll give that a shot in a bit.

Comment: My pleasure, as I said, "fetch" is not a core function, and you need to replace it with your own. For example, if you are using MySQL, You can use mysqli_fetch_array instead.

Comment: This worked and resulted in what I was trying to accomplish. Still playing with the PIVOT query though.

Comment: Good luck... :)